# Error Code = -1005 randomly, with intermittent internet and Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, alamofire

In my application when I try to obtain data Alamofire, but present connection problems, randomly presented the `error = Optional (Error Domain = NSURLErrorDomain Code = -1005 "The network connection was lost."` so `responseObject` is `nil`.  What is the best way to handle the data so that when it is  `nil`, it’s make the call again?

Attached my call to the server:

```
 
makeCall(dirurl, param: parame, completionHandler: { responseObject, error in
```

```
        print("responseObject = \(responseObject); error = \(error)")

        //here should control for the call is generated until it is different from nil

        self.datosRequest = responseObject!


        self.datosContenido = self.datosRequest["datos"] as! NSDictionary
        self.extractData()
        self.tableGastosComunes.reloadData()
        return
    })
```

func makeCall(dirurl: String, param : [String:NSObject], completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> ()) {

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, dirurl, parameters: param, encoding:.URL).responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let value):
            completionHandler(value as? NSDictionary, nil)
        case .Failure(let error):
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check first either response is error or success. if its error then based on the error code you can manage what action to perform      https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, but I meant what would be the right way or the best practice, that n'm sure if it is correct to make a recursive call to obtain data.

Comment: if connection was lost , check network connectivity, if network is available then send service cal again otherwise notify user about internet connectivity error.You can have maximum retries check like max 3 retries.If user reaches maximum retries then he might be having slow network so don't expect the user will be getting data